# How to remove a button when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not very familiar with Javascript and I'm doing a function where if a button is clicked, it would remove the button using its ID.

I have tried doing different solutions where I would get the IDs but I am stuck about the logic of it.

When I click the button it does not do anything.

```js
var myBtn = document.getElementById("my-btn"),
  mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = myBtn.innerHTML;
myBtn.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myBtn); <
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="my-btn">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a typo?  It replaces the button just fine if you remove the syntax error at the end of the JavaScript.  (Note that it also does this immediately rather than on button click, since the code has no click handler...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the button's `onclick` event for that:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("my-btn");

button.onclick = function() {
  //this code will execute whenever the button is clicked
  //inside the handler, "this" refers to the button
  this.parentNode.removeChild(button);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="my-btn">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! But how would you remove the button permanently? Because whenever I refresh the page the button still comes back.

Comment: @JavsP.Aqui That is a very different question. Consider searching for that portion elsewhere or asking a separate question; Anis has answered the question  that you asked.

Comment: @TylerRoper Okay. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```html
<button type="button" id="MyButton">Click me</button>
```

removing the button clicked:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('MyButton');

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
this.remove();
});
```

to just hide it replace `this.remove();` by `this.classList.add('hidden');` and with css you can do `.hidden {display:none;}` OR adding `this.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');`

[remove docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<button id="me"onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

JS

```
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("me");
  x.remove();
  }
</script>
```